# Error: EACCES: permission denied when trying to install ESLint using npm

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, eslint

I'm trying to install [ESLint](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started) with npm by going:

```
npm install -g eslint
```

However I get the following error:

```
Deans-Air:~ deangibson$ npm install -g eslint
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /Users/deangibson/.npm/eslint/2.4.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! Darwin 15.3.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "eslint"
npm ERR! node v4.2.3
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall mkdir

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:35:25',
npm ERR!      '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:47:53',
npm ERR!      'FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/deangibson/npm-debug.log
```

And to be honest I get this every single time I try and install something with npm. Sometimes using 'sudo' works, sometimes it doesn't... How can I fix this once and for all?

Answer (score 149):

Use `--unsafe-perm=true` and `--allow-root` flags with `npm` install like below:-

```
sudo npm install -g eslint --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

it worked like charm for me.

Comment: If it's a local package obviously don't use g. It can have a big effect on the result

Comment: This works on `macos`. Maybe it's unsafe, but it's the only solution that worked for me.

Comment: It not unsafe to use it actually, coz installing npm modules globally requires you to use sudo, reason is it creates files in root directories

Comment: This alone did not help in my case, had to use ```-i``` flag as well with sudo.

Answer (score 53):

This problem is well documented in the [npm docs: Fixing npm permissions](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions).

You have 2 solutions available:

**Option 1**: Change npm's default directory to a hidden directory in your home folder

```
mkdir ~/.npm-global
npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
source ~/.profile
```

---

**Option 2**: Use a package manager that takes care of this for you

```
brew install node
```

Comment: Option 2 worked well but I utilized the ~/.npm directory as my dotfiles had already configured that location (but I forgot!)

Comment: upvoting for option 2.  I should have done this a long time ago :sweat-smile:

Comment: If you use option one, you might end up with this problem, so I don't recommend this at all: https://askubuntu.com/questions/452860/usr-bin-sudo-must-be-owned-by-uid-0-and-have-the-setuid-bit-set#471503
The root user should own /user/bin

Comment: Option 4: Install using Yarn with `sudo yarn global add <package-name>`

Comment: Do no use option 1, it will ruin your sudo.

Comment: @GermánBarletta I used option 1, how do i fix it, please help?

Comment: ugh, sorry to hear that @ShivanshSingh, I followed the suggestions that appear on the link that Joe shared. Don't worry, it's easy to fix.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/452860/usr-bin-sudo-must-be-owned-by-uid-0-and-have-the-setuid-bit-set#471503

Comment: how to do the option 2 in linux? specifically in debian?

Comment: Option 2 was the right answer.

Comment: Option 2 is great. Using sudo to install NPM dependencies seems wildly dangerous to me.

Answer (score 11):

Running the following command solved the issue for me while installing my packages.json :

```
 sudo npm install --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

To install only the package which caused the issue:

```
  sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root eslint
```

Answer (score 7):

guys, I have fixed it simplely by

```
sudo npm install
```

I have tried the toppest answer, it works well too.

Comment: plus one for *"toppest"*.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm=true eslint
```

is sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

Use **sudo before tns** and it is work for me

Example:

```
sudo tns create Tekmo --template tns-template-hello-world
```

if I have used sudo then not found error like to create *postinstall.js*

> Error: EACCES: permission denied

Answer (score 3):

for MacOS users having this issue!

while starting the react server, write `sudo npm start` not `npm start`.

That solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

you can login as root using `sudo su`. First run the command `sudo su` on your terminal, then give your login password. Finally execute your expected command `npm install -g eslint`. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

For MAC user provide the access permission to project directory folder

1. Right click on project directory folder
2. Select get info
3. Provide the access permission - Apply to inclosed items

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple permissions error and one of the ways to resolve it is to simply delete the node_modules folder and run npm install again, making sure you are not the root user.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question I just update my node version to 16.x (before 14.18), the problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if you're in a virtual environment, You can remove the "-g" (global install) and just go with

*npm install eslint*

to install it in that venv

alternatively, you can go to the base environment and install it globally

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

#### Just had the same error while running

```
npm install -g @ionic/cli native-run cordova-res
```

#### To fix, run the following

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade -y
```

I had read the already present solutions but thought there was something else, UNSAFE isn't a safe keyword, lol. While running the command with the --unsafe-perm=true, I noticed it downloading what seemed to be update binaries.
So, I updated and tried again.