# Node-gyp. MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

I was trying to install sharp module, which requires:
    c++ compiler - I downloaded Visual Studio 2017 and visual c++ build tools
    node-gyp - It was installed successfully

But running 'npm install -g sharp' I got many errors

- gyp ERR! stack Error: `E:\VS\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed
  with exit code: 1
- gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit
  (C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\li
  \build.js:258:23)
- gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
- gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
- gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
  (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
- gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
- gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"
- "C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\nod
  _modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
- gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sharp
- gyp ERR! node -v v8.5.0
- gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
- gyp ERR! not ok
- npm WARN Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink
- 'C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sharp\node_modu
  es\color-name\package.json'
- npm WARN  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink
  'C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sharp\node_m
  dules\color-name\package.json'
- npm WARN   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink
  \'C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
  \sharp\node_modules\color-name\package.json\'',
- npm WARN   errno: -4048,
- npm WARN   code: 'EPERM',
- npm WARN   syscall: 'unlink',
- npm WARN   path:
- 'C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sharp\node_modules\color-name\package.json'
  }
- npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! sharp@0.18.3
  install: `node-gyp rebuild` npm ERR! Exit status 1

If it matters - I'm a Windows user

Comment: Have you installed nodejs?

Comment: Yes, I have it installed

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like build tools are not installed, You have to install the build tools for Windows

`npm install --global windows-build-tools`

[more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53009640/557396)

Comment: Is there any solution for ubuntu system?

Comment: the correct command is `npm install --global windows-build-tools`

Answer (score 2):

Just came across a similar problem and after a lot of searches online, it seems like a problem with the latest node version that automatically integrate and use v8 engine, that older dependencies doesn't support.
it seems like an ms-build problem, but that's probably not the real issue. I have tried the following without success:

1. Downgre node version to 10.8.0 and then installing
2. Remove `%APPDATA%\npm-cache\_libvips` and installing from [here](https://github.com/lovell/sharp-libvips/releases/download/v8.7.4/libvips-8.7.4-win32-x64.tar.gz)
3. Run `npm install --global windows-build-tool`

This is how I solved it:

1. Uninstall nodejs and npm (and make sure the folder C:/Program Files/nodejs was deleted and also if any npm install location is still remaining, delete it. An example is C:\Users<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm)
2. Install Node version 14.16.0 (I recommend using [nvm](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/) for this task)
3. Update npm to its latest version by running `npm install npm@latest -g`
4. Navigate to your project's folder (where the installation previously failed) and run `npm install --ignore-scripts`
5. (On a side note), if that's being used with `node-sass` you'd might want to also run this: `npm rebuild node-sass --force --ignore-scripts`

Comment: unfortunately `npm install npm@latest -g` leads to more problems...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54652381/updating-npm-when-using-nvm-windows

Comment: I just try step 4 and 5, it works for me (no need to reinstall `node` and `npm`).

Answer (score 1):

When you install the vs_BuildTools.exe by using this command

npm install --global windows-build-tools

if you encounter some errors, try installing manually.

Then don't forget to add the msbuild.exe to your system path.

i.e. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64

when this is not in your path, the system tries to use another msbuild.exe from your .NET installation.

I fixed mine like that.