# Updating npm when using nvm-windows

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, nvm, nvm-windows

I'm using nvm-windows version 1.1.7.

I just installed node 11.9.0.

nvm installs npm version 6.5.0 together with this node version.
However, there's npm version 6.7.0 available already.

When I now do `npm i -g npm` I get:

```
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! Refusing to delete C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd: is outside C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm and not a link
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.
```

I found no way to avoid this.

Comment: Maybe Volta is the tool we are looking for? Check https://volta.sh/

Comment: Actually, I also would recommend switching to another node version manager, such as Volta or fnm that both support Windows. Or, if you are using pnpm (I love it :-D), this has `pnpm env` as builtin command. https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/node-environment-managers/ is a good overview from June 2022

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Several workarounds are available in this Issue on the `nvm-windows` github repo:

https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/issues/300

There are examples using DOS, PowerShell, bash, and batch scripts.

Comment: Thanks! The batch script from https://gist.github.com/johnmcase/d31b799b9030327091a0e74880e4c530 worked well for me.

Comment: In my version of the batch script I now added the ` --force` option in the call to npm to avoid an updating error I got: `node "!node_path!\node_modules\npm2\bin\npm-cli.js" i npm@!wanted_version! -g --force`

Comment: https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/issues/300#issuecomment-798776683 this also worked for me.

Answer (score 85):

This is a duplicate from my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50955293/491553

Here is how I upgrade npm when running nvm-windows:

```
cd %APPDATA%\nvm\v14.20.0           # or whatever node version you're using
move npm npm-old
move npm.cmd npm-old.cmd
move npx npx-old
move npx.cmd npx-old.cmd
cd node_modules\
move npm npm-old
cd npm-old\bin
node npm-cli.js i -g npm@latest --force
```

And boom, upgraded.

Comment: To find your nvm install path you can run get-command nvm from powershell.

Comment: I have used this command to upgrade to a specific version
``node npm-cli.js i -g npm@x.y.z``

Comment: I think we have to use --force in the last command. Btw thanks for the answer.

Comment: Those `mv` commands above are for powershell, yet you can't use `%appdata%` syntax in PowerShell so use `$ENV:AppData` in its place. Turned out that my `choco install -y nvm` put nvm in `C:\ProgramData\nvm` so I had to use `cd $ENV:ProgramData\nvm\v14.17.1`. And yes, I had to add the force flag `node npm-cli.js i -g npm@latest --force`.

Comment: If there's npx in the directory then even that has to be renamed. In my case I've renamed that as well. `mv npx npx-old` `mv npx.cmd npx-old.cm`

Comment: If after the update you're experiencing errors with .ps1 files - it's unrelated, and can be fixed by deleting the .ps1 commands: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/1821

Comment: I'm sorry. I was using `mv` from cygwin. The DOS `move` command should work too. I updated the script so it works now in vanilla DOS.

Comment: Adding to what @hashBender said previously, we have to change the names of `npm.ps1` and `npx.ps1` to `-old` as well.

Comment: @ryan-shillington if you can add both these files as well to the answer that would be great 

Comment: It's almost too easy!

Comment: If only it were easy though ... using node 14.18.0 I get errors like `npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\roryk\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.18.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\.node-gyp.DELETE\node_modules\@npmcli' -> 'C:\Users\roryk\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.18.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\@npmcli'`

Comment: > npm WARN  I sure hope you know what you are doing. 

Lol, npm throwing shades at me for running code from stackoverflow :(

Comment: @kaushalpranav I don't see any `*.ps1` files. Where do you see that?

Answer (score 12):

I have windows 10 operating system.

I installed in following way.

```
cd %APPDATA%\nvm\v8.11.3
move npm 5.6.0
move npm.cmd 5.6.0.cmd
cd node_modules\
move npm 5.6.0
cd 5.6.0\bin
node npm-cli.js i -g npm@latest
```

Comment: For newer versions, you must do the same with `npx` and `npx.cmd`. 
Using Gitbash on Windows Terminal the last command must be: `node npm-cli.js i -g npm@latest --force`. If you have a failed attempt, make sure to clean up the `nvm\v8.11.3` folder.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me and it updated npx (automatically) too.

Comment: How does update existing global packages works? `node npm-cli.js update -g --force` not working!

Answer (score 7):

I had to force it :-/

When it came to

```
node npm-cli.js i -g npm@latest
```

I'd rather had to use

```
node npm-cli.js i -g npm@latest --force
```

probably to overcome a permission error involved in overwriting the "C:\Program Files\nodejs" link.

Comment: Ditto - had to force it, but it worked. Glad someone else tried this first though 

Comment: Just FYI that `--force` did not work for me, and instead left npm in a "broken" state where it had deleted the old install but been unable to install the new one. I fixed it by creating a new folder, running `yarn init`, then `yarn add npm`, then I copied the contents of its `npm` folder into the (now basically empty) `...../nvm/XXX/node_modules/npm` folder, then running: `node ((Get-Item "C:\Program Files\nodejs").Target[0] + "\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js").ToString() i -g npm@latest`

Answer (score 6):

1. download this [updateNpm.bat](https://gist.github.com/nokidding/aafaf90adc80cbce54b676340817bb13) file
2. open powershell in that same folder and run this command `updateNpm.bat latest`

Comment: Oh wow, after so many tries that perfectly worked!!! THANK YOU

Answer (score 4):

I tried the script and other solutions, this by far is the easiest way:

1. Navigate to the relevant Node folder (`cd C:\Users\yourUser\AppData\Roaming\nvm\vxx.xx.x`)
2. rename npm -> npm2
3. rename npm.cmd -> npm2.cmd
4. rename npx -> npx2
5. rename npx.cmd -> npx2.cmd
6. Run `npm2 install -g npm@your-version`
7. the new npm will create npm, npm.cmd, npx, npx.cmd files, so you can remove the previous renamed files

Comment: For step 1, this Powershell command will launch an Explorer window in the correct folder: `start ((Get-Item "C:\Program Files\nodejs").Target[0])`

Answer (score 3):

For me I only get the problem when updating npm with npm v6.
So using a newer version of npm via npx to run the upgrade works for me.

```
For the very newest version
npx npm install -g npm

Or use a specific version
npx npm@7 install -g npm@7
```

Comment: didn't work for me...same error.

Comment: Tested with _nvmw 1.1.10_ / _node 14.21.2_ / _npm 6.14.17_ and successfully update to _npm 7.24.2_ w/ `npx npm@7 install -g npm@7` and then can update with `npm install` directly. Note that `npx npm@7 install -g npm` return same error.

Comment: Got it working with a slight tweak: `npx npm@7 install npm@latest`. Other methods didn't seem to overwrite correct files. Had to specify the `@latest` to force it somehow?

Answer (score 2):

I also found it necessary to install `windows-nvm` to `c:\nvm` and `c:\nodejs` to prevent issues with unsupported paths with spaces.

```sh
rm C:\nodejs\npm*
rm C:\nodejs\npx*
mv C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm-old
node C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm-old\bin\npm-cli.js i -g npm@next
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem today, the way i solved it was installing latest node with nvm then copying the npm files from latest to the version i am on.

```
nvm install latest
cd AppData/Roaming/nvm/LATEST
xcopy npm.cmd ../LTS && xcopy npm ../LTS && xcopy node_modules/npm ../LTS
```

I then confirmed it working by trying to compile my code that breaks on latest.

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me:

```
curl -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

If you already have git bash installed, use it there.

Comment: The question has windows as a tag and the text makes this fact pretty clear as well, downloading a shellscript isn't going to do anything.

Comment: @Timotheus It does .... and it will first uninstall the current version of npm then install the latest. It worked for me ....

Comment: In both powershell and cmd I'm getting a `'sh' is not recognised...`

Comment: if you have git bash installed, try it there