# Convert SASS to CSS without using Ruby or Python?

Tags: npm, gruntjs, node-sass

I am having a grunt file using which I am trying to convert SASS to CSS but I am unable to. I want to do it without using Ruby or Python. I only want to use NPM packages.

Comment: You can use Node-sass

Comment: Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable. - getting this error after npm install --save-dev node-sass.

Comment: Show us grunt configuration. Your error clearly shows, that you need install Python.

Comment: Via NPM, use [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) or [node-sass-chokidar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass-chokidar). You have to remove grunt file, move to npm style (package.json file).

Comment: Then what to use instead of grunt ?

Answer (score 2):

At the current date it is impossible.

Certain versions of node-sass have precompiled binaries, but if you aren't a supported platform then there's nothing you can do, install ruby or python.

See:

https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1176

https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2173

[Node.js: Python not found exception due to node-sass and node-gyp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45801457/node-js-python-not-found-exception-due-to-node-sass-and-node-gyp)

Answer (score 2):

You can convert online using https://sass2css.herokuapp.com

And it provides several options / configurations. Such as

1. Indent Style and Width
2. Style Output
3. Autoprefixer Toggle