# node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

**Trying to set up Angular App on existing project. On npm install under project dir, getting dependency error.**

**I git cloned existing angular project and setting up my dev environment. FYI I am behind proxy and firewall. Fetching node modules from our artifactory. I have made sure .npmrc file points to the right registry. BTW I have different .npmrc files. One is part of the project and other one is under home directory. both have some diff and they point to different internal artifactories.**

```
Global =>
node -v 12.6.0
npm -v 6.9.0
Angular -v 8.1.2

Local Angular -v 7.3.9

ng version
Your global Angular CLI version (8.1.2) is greater than your local
version (7.3.9). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".    

Angular CLI: 7.3.9
Node: 12.6.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 7.2.15
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.13.9
@angular-devkit/core              8.3.8
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.3.9
@angular/cdk                      7.3.7
@angular/cli                      7.3.9
@angular/fire                     5.2.1
@angular/material                 7.3.7
@ngtools/webpack                  7.3.9
@schematics/angular               7.3.9
@schematics/update                0.13.9
rxjs                              6.5.3
typescript                        3.2.4
webpack                           4.41.0
```

**Not sure why I am getting Python error but after digging some npm tickets, I also did - 
npm config set python "/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python"
python -v 3.7.3**

**Error on npm install**

```
npm info lifecycle minizlib@1.2.1~install: minizlib@1.2.1
npm info lifecycle tar@4.4.8~install: tar@4.4.8
npm info lifecycle node-pre-gyp@0.12.0~install: node-pre-gyp@0.12.0
npm info lifecycle fsevents@1.2.9~install: fsevents@1.2.9

> fsevents@1.2.9 install /Users/user/project/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node_modules/fsevents
> node install

node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.12.0
node-pre-gyp info using node@12.6.0 | darwin | x64
node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/Users/user/project/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node" (not found)
node-pre-gyp http GET https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.2.9/fse-v1.2.9-node-v72-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for fsevents@1.2.9 and node@12.6.0 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error self signed certificate in certificate chain 
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@12.6.0 | darwin | x64
gyp info ok 
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@12.6.0 | darwin | x64
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack 
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:297:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:203:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:430:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:203:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:588:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.6.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/user/project/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node" "--module_name=fse" "--module_path=/Users/user/project/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64" "--napi_version=4" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v72" "--python=/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/user/project/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v12.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.6.0/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/user/project/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/user/project/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64 --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72 --python=/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/user/project/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:203:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.6.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.6.0/bin/node" "/Users/user/project/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/user/project/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.6.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.12.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.6.0/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/user/project/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/user/project/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64 --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72 --python=/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python' (1)
npm info lifecycle fsevents@1.2.9~install: Failed to exec install script
npm info lifecycle abbrev@1.1.1~install: abbrev@1.1.1
npm info lifecycle ansi-regex@2.1.1~install: ansi-regex@2.1.1
....
npm info lifecycle minizlib@1.2.1~install: minizlib@1.2.1
npm info lifecycle tar@4.4.8~install: tar@4.4.8
npm info lifecycle node-pre-gyp@0.12.0~install: node-pre-gyp@0.12.0
npm info lifecycle fsevents@1.2.9~install: fsevents@1.2.9


> fsevents@1.2.9 install /Users/user/project/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-webpack/node_modules/fsevents
> node install



node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.12.0
node-pre-gyp info using node@12.6.0 | darwin | x64
node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/Users/user/project/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node" (not found)
node-pre-gyp http GET https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.2.9/fse-v1.2.9-node-v72-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for fsevents@1.2.9 and node@12.6.0 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error self signed certificate in certificate chain 
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@12.6.0 | darwin | x64
gyp info ok 
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@12.6.0 | darwin | x64
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack 
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:297:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:203:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:430:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:203:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:588:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.6.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/user/project/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node" "--module_name=fse" "--module_path=/Users/user/project/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64" "--napi_version=4" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v72" "--python=/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/user/project/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v12.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.6.0/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/user/project/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/user/project/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64 --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72 --python=/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/user/project/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:203:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.6.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.6.0/bin/node" "/Users/user/project/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/user/project/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.6.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.12.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.6.0/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/user/project/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/user/project/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64 --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72 --python=/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python' (1)
npm info lifecycle fsevents@1.2.9~install: Failed to exec install script
npm info lifecycle abbrev@1.1.1~install: abbrev@1.1.1
npm info lifecycle ansi-regex@2.1.1~install: ansi-regex@2.1.1
npm info lifecycle aproba@1.2.0~install: aproba@1.2.0
npm info lifecycle balanced-match@1.0.0~install: balanced-match@1.0.0
npm info lifecycle chownr@1.1.1~install: chownr@1.1.1
npm info lifecycle code-point-at@1.1.0~install: code-point-at@1.1.0
npm info lifecycle concat-map@0.0.1~install: concat-map@0.0.1
npm info lifecycle brace-expansion@1.1.11~install: brace-expansion@1.1.11
npm info lifecycle console-control-strings@1.1.0~install: console-control-strings@1.1.0
npm info lifecycle core-util-is@1.0.2~install: core-util-is@1.0.2
npm info lifecycle deep-extend@0.6.0~install: deep-extend@0.6.0
npm info lifecycle delegates@1.0.0~install: delegates@1.0.0
npm info lifecycle detect-libc@1.0.3~install: detect-libc@1.0.3
npm info lifecycle fs.realpath@1.0.0~install: fs.realpath@1.0.0
npm info lifecycle has-unicode@2.0.1~install: has-unicode@2.0.1
npm info lifecycle inherits@2.0.3~install: inherits@2.0.3
npm info lifecycle ini@1.3.5~install: ini@1.3.5
npm info lifecycle isarray@1.0.0~install: isarray@1.0.0
npm info lifecycle minimatch@3.0.4~install: minimatch@3.0.4
npm info lifecycle ignore-walk@3.0.1~install: ignore-walk@3.0.1
npm info lifecycle minimist@1.2.0~install: minimist@1.2.0
npm info lifecycle minimist@0.0.8~install: minimist@0.0.8
npm info lifecycle mkdirp@0.5.1~install: mkdirp@0.5.1
npm info lifecycle ms@2.0.0~install: ms@2.0.0
npm info lifecycle debug@2.6.9~install: debug@2.6.9
npm info lifecycle npm-bundled@1.0.5~install: npm-bundled@1.0.5
npm info lifecycle npm-packlist@1.1.12~install: npm-packlist@1.1.12
npm info lifecycle number-is-nan@1.0.1~install: number-is-nan@1.0.1
npm info lifecycle is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0~install: is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0
npm info lifecycle object-assign@4.1.1~install: object-assign@4.1.1
npm info lifecycle os-homedir@1.0.2~install: os-homedir@1.0.2
npm info lifecycle os-tmpdir@1.0.2~install: os-tmpdir@1.0.2
npm info lifecycle osenv@0.1.5~install: osenv@0.1.5
npm info lifecycle nopt@4.0.1~install: nopt@4.0.1
npm info lifecycle path-is-absolute@1.0.1~install: path-is-absolute@1.0.1
npm info lifecycle process-nextick-args@2.0.0~install: process-nextick-args@2.0.0
npm info lifecycle safe-buffer@5.1.2~install: safe-buffer@5.1.2
npm info lifecycle safer-buffer@2.1.2~install: safer-buffer@2.1.2
npm info lifecycle iconv-lite@0.4.23~install: iconv-lite@0.4.23
npm info lifecycle sax@1.2.4~install: sax@1.2.4
npm info lifecycle needle@2.2.4~install: needle@2.2.4
npm info lifecycle semver@5.6.0~install: semver@5.6.0
npm info lifecycle set-blocking@2.0.0~install: set-blocking@2.0.0
npm info lifecycle signal-exit@3.0.2~install: signal-exit@3.0.2
npm info lifecycle string_decoder@1.1.1~install: string_decoder@1.1.1
npm info lifecycle strip-ansi@3.0.1~install: strip-ansi@3.0.1
npm info lifecycle string-width@1.0.2~install: string-width@1.0.2
npm info lifecycle strip-json-comments@2.0.1~install: strip-json-comments@2.0.1
npm info lifecycle rc@1.2.8~install: rc@1.2.8
npm info lifecycle util-deprecate@1.0.2~install: util-deprecate@1.0.2
npm info lifecycle readable-stream@2.3.6~install: readable-stream@2.3.6
npm info lifecycle are-we-there-yet@1.1.5~install: are-we-there-yet@1.1.5
npm info lifecycle wide-align@1.1.3~install: wide-align@1.1.3
npm info lifecycle gauge@2.7.4~install: gauge@2.7.4
npm info lifecycle npmlog@4.1.2~install: npmlog@4.1.2
npm info lifecycle wrappy@1.0.2~install: wrappy@1.0.2
npm info lifecycle once@1.4.0~install: once@1.4.0
npm info lifecycle inflight@1.0.6~install: inflight@1.0.6
npm info lifecycle glob@7.1.2~install: glob@7.1.2
npm info lifecycle rimraf@2.6.2~install: rimraf@2.6.2
npm info lifecycle yallist@3.0.3~install: yallist@3.0.3
npm info lifecycle minipass@2.3.5~install: minipass@2.3.5
npm info lifecycle fs-minipass@1.2.5~install: fs-minipass@1.2.5
npm info lifecycle minizlib@1.1.1~install: minizlib@1.1.1
npm info lifecycle tar@4.4.8~install: tar@4.4.8
npm info lifecycle node-pre-gyp@0.12.0~install: node-pre-gyp@0.12.0
npm info lifecycle grpc@1.20.0~install: grpc@1.20.0

> grpc@1.20.0 install /Users/user/project/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.12.0
node-pre-gyp info using node@12.6.0 | darwin | x64
node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/Users/user/project/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node" (not found)
node-pre-gyp http GET https://artifactory.user/grpc-precompiled-binaries-remote/grpc/v1.20.0/node-v72-darwin-x64-unknown.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for grpc@1.20.0 and node@12.6.0 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error unable to get local issuer certificate 
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@12.6.0 | darwin | x64
gyp info ok 
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@12.6.0 | darwin | x64
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack 
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:297:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:203:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:430:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:203:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:588:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.6.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=/Users/user/project/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=/Users/user/project/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-darwin-x64-unknown" "--napi_version=4" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v72" "--python=/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/user/project/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v12.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.6.0/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/Users/user/project/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/Users/user/project/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-darwin-x64-unknown --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72 --python=/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/user/project/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:203:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.6.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.6.0/bin/node" "/Users/user/project/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/user/project/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.6.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.12.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.6.0/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/Users/user/project/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/Users/user/project/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-darwin-x64-unknown --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72 --python=/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python' (1)
npm info lifecycle grpc@1.20.0~install: Failed to exec install script
npm timing action:install Completed in 9386ms
npm WARN rollback Rolling back @firebase/firestore@1.2.2 failed (this is probably harmless): EINVAL: invalid argument, rmdir '/Users/user/project/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns'
npm timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1007ms
npm timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 41431ms
npm WARN bootstrap@4.3.1 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.3.1 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.14.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN user@0.18.1-test-Sept.1 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 install: `node install`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 install: `node install`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-webpack/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 install: `node install`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 install: `node install`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 install: `node install`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 install: `node install`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.20.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.20.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm timing npm Completed in 42596ms

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2019-10-08T00_37_29_682Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 9):

I see that you are using Firebase. You should upgrade it to the `@latest` version as they are still shipping the old version of `grpc` that does not work with Node v12.

After I upgraded firebase to the latest version (`@8.2.3` from `@5.5.7`) the issue disappeared on my side (thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52181234/2940502))

```
npm i firebase@latest
```

The official [issue in grpc GitHub repo](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/834).

Answer (score 3):

Please try to run the below command to solve this problem.

```
npm install grpc --verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade the node version to 12. (mine was 16)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).