# NPM Install: Pre-built binaries not installable for grpc@1.24.2 and node@6.16.0

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, node-modules, grpc

Im trying to install my Angular project via `npm i`, so i get the following error:

```
npm i

> grpc@1.20.0 install C:\www\innpactia\node_modules\grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for grpc@1.20.0 and node@6.16.0 (node-v48 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error unable to get local issuer certificate
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
gyp ERR! stack     at Error (native)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1092:38)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:609:8)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:439:38)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
```

---

Node version: `6.16.0`

NPM version: `6.13.7`

NVM version: `1.1.7`

Python version: `3.8.1`

Angular version: `7.2.5`

---

Already try the following commands with differents versions of node: (`6.16.0`, `10.0.0`, `10.15.0`, `12.14.1`)

`npm install grpc@latest`

`npm --build-from-source install bcrypt`

also add manually `"node-pre-gyp": "0.12.0"` as a **devDev** in my package.json

---

Any of this alternatives works.

Comment: Your node version is very old (6.x, while the latest Long Term Support is 12.x).  Try [an upgrade](https://nodejs.org/en/download/).  In my experience, it's the version of node that matters for binaries.

Comment: Actually it looks like someone else had the same problem.  [See that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52164351/pre-built-binaries-not-found-for-grpc1-10-1-and-node10-9-0)