# How do I fix all these dependency errors for a React app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

```
> grpc@1.13.1 install C:\Users\HP\Desktop\react-slack-clone\node_modules\grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(403): https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.13.1/node-v72-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.13.1 and node@12.18.3 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for grpc@1.13.1 and node@12.18.3 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error Connection closed while downloading tarball file
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python2" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python2" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if the py launcher can be used to find Python 2
gyp ERR! find Python - "py.exe" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Python27\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Python37\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
gypgyp ERR! find Python
gyp  ERR!ERR!  find Pythonfind Python
 **********************************************************
gypgyp  ERR!ERR!  find Pythonfind Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
 Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
gypgyp  ERR!ERR!  find Pythonfind Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
 Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
gypgyp  ERR!ERR!  find Pythonfind Python you can try one of the following options:
 checking if "python" can be used
gypgyp  ERR!ERR!  find Pythonfind Python - Use the switch --python="C:\Path\To\python.exe"
 - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
gypgyp  ERR!ERR!  find Pythonfind Python checking if "python2" can be used
   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
gypgyp  ERR!ERR!  find Pythonfind Python - "python2" is not in PATH or produced an error
 - Set the environment variable PYTHON
gypgyp  ERR!ERR!  find Pythonfind Python checking if "python3" can be used
 - Set the npm configuration variable python:
gypgyp  ERR!ERR!  find Pythonfind Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
   npm config set python "C:\Path\To\python.exe"
gypgyp  ERR!ERR!  find Pythonfind Python checking if the py launcher can be used to find Python 2
 For more information consult the documentation at:
gypgyp  ERR!ERR!  find Pythonfind Python - "py.exe" is not in PATH or produced an error
 https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
gypgyp  ERR!ERR!  find Pythonfind Python checking if Python is C:\Python27\python.exe
 **********************************************************
gypgyp  ERR!ERR!  find Pythonfind Python - "C:\Python27\python.exe" could not be run

gyp ERR! find Pythongyp checking if Python is C:\Python37\python.exe
 gypERR!  ERR!configure error
find Pythongyp - "C:\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
 gypERR!  ERR!stack  Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
gypfind Python
gypERR!  ERR!stack      at PythonFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:307:47)
find Pythongyp **********************************************************
gyp ERR!  ERR!stack      at PythonFinder.runChecks (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:136:21)
find Pythongyp You need to install the latest version of Python.
 gypERR!  ERR!stack      at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:225:16)
find Pythongyp Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
 gypERR!  ERR!stack      at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:271:16)
find Pythongyp you can try one of the following options:
 gypERR!  ERR!stack      at exithandler (child_process.js:310:5)
find Pythongyp - Use the switch --python="C:\Path\To\python.exe"
 gypERR!  ERR!stack      at ChildProcess.errorhandler (child_process.js:322:5)
find Pythongyp   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
 gypERR!  ERR!stack      at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
find Pythongyp - Set the environment variable PYTHON
 gypERR!  ERR!stack      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
find Pythongyp - Set the npm configuration variable python:
 gypERR!  ERR!stack      at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
find Pythongyp   npm config set python "C:\Path\To\python.exe"
 gypERR!  ERR!stack      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
find Pythongyp For more information consult the documentation at:
 gypERR!  ERR!System  Windows_NT 10.0.19041
find Pythongyp https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
 gypERR!  ERR!command  "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\react-slack-clone\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown\\grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\react-slack-clone\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown" "--napi_version=6" "--node_abi_napi=napi"
find Pythongyp **********************************************************
 gypERR!  ERR!cwd  C:\Users\HP\Desktop\react-slack-clone\node_modules\grpc
find Pythongyp
 ERR! node -v v12.18.3
gypgyp ERR!  ERR!node-gyp -v  v5.1.0
configure errorgyp
 gyp ERR!ERR!  not okstack
 Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:307:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:136:21)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:225:16)
gypnode-pre-gyp ERR!  ERR!stack      at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:271:16)
build errorgyp
ERR!node-pre-gyp  stackERR!     at exithandler (child_process.js:310:5)
 gypstack  Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\HP\Desktop\react-slack-clone\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Users\HP\Desktop\react-slack-clone\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown --napi_version=6 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
ERR!node-pre-gyp  stackERR!     at ChildProcess.errorhandler (child_process.js:322:5)
 gypstack      at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\react-slack-clone\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
ERR!node-pre-gyp  stackERR!     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
 gypstack      at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
ERR!node-pre-gyp  stackERR!     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
 gypstack      at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
ERR!node-pre-gyp  stackERR!     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
 gypstack      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
ERR!node-pre-gyp  stackERR!     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
 gypSystem  Windows_NT 10.0.19041
ERR!node-pre-gyp  SystemERR! Windows_NT 10.0.19041
 gypcommand  "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\react-slack-clone\\node_modules\\grpc\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
ERR!node-pre-gyp  commandERR! "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\react-slack-clone\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown\\grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\react-slack-clone\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown" "--napi_version=6" "--node_abi_napi=napi"
 gypcwd  C:\Users\HP\Desktop\react-slack-clone\node_modules\grpc
ERR!node-pre-gyp  cwdERR! C:\Users\HP\Desktop\react-slack-clone\node_modules\grpc
 gypnode -v  v12.18.3
ERR!node-pre-gyp  node -vERR! v12.18.3
 gypnode-pre-gyp -v  v0.10.3
ERR!node-pre-gyp  node-gyp -vERR! v5.1.0
 gypnot ok
ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\HP\Desktop\react-slack-clone\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Users\HP\Desktop\react-slack-clone\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown --napi_version=6 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.13.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.13.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-18T14_30_53_303Z-debug.log
```

Too many errors to even know where to begin...  maybe someone who understands this better than I will notice what's going on.  My take is it's version errors.  It looks like I need python installed, which I don't.  Fine.  But maybe a Node version error, as well?

The real issue here is that this began with a git clone, I was told I just needed to run npm i in the foler to get all dependencies installed, but I'm coming up with problems.  What I noticed was that going to a subdirector wasn't giving me what I should have (i.e. localhost:3000/login wasn't showing what it should for that route).  I went back to manually install react-router and react-router-dom, but still no fix.  Now I'm seeing all these crazy errors, and realizing I must not have all dependencies.  What went wrong with trying to install dependencies as I was told?

Any help is much appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: Did everything go smoothly the first time you did an `npm install`? I see you hit a `403` error when it was trying to download the `node-pre-gyp` tarball.

Comment: Seemed to.  I don't remember seeing errors.  But then I noticed I didn't have all the dependencies I was supposed to have.  I went back to clear out the cache, as well, as try again, but just more errors.  I'm starting to wonder if I'm not just best deleting Node completely, and reinstalling...

Comment: I'd try resetting the `package.json` to the original before you updated `react-router` and `react-router-dom`, delete the `package-lock.json` and the `node_modules` folder and try `npm i` again. - `rm package-lock.json && rm -rf node_modules` and then `npm i`. Also scan the terminal output and make sure you don't get this again - `node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(403): https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.13.1/node-v72-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz` because it looks like the failure to download this dep is causing the issue

Comment: So, it looks like you're on Node 12. May be `grpc@1.13.1` doesn't play well with that version of Node. Try updating grpc - `npm install grpc` and then `npm i`

Comment: Also look at this - looks like a similar issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52164351/pre-built-binaries-not-found-for-grpc1-10-1-and-node10-9-0