# gyp ERR! npm install

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, npm

is there any soluation for this error? I'm receiving that while running npm install on centos 7.
npm version = 8.5.0
nodejs version = v16.14.1

receiving error:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNGi4.jpg)

```
npm ERR! path /usr/share/nginx/html/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /usr/bin/node /usr/share/nginx/html/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/usr/bin/node',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/usr/share/nginx/html/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.14.1 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "/usr/bin/python3" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: /usr/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /usr/share/nginx/html/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /usr/share/nginx/html/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  /usr/bin/python3 Error: not found: /usr/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/usr/share/nginx/html/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/usr/share/nginx/html/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /usr/share/nginx/html/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "/usr/bin/python3", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at E (/usr/share/nginx/html/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 3.10.0-1160.45.1.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/share/nginx/html/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /usr/share/nginx/html/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1
```

Comment: Install Python 3 I guess.

Comment: @Andy not fixed

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have a Node module that depends on Python.  As you're on CentOS you'll need to run:

```
sudo yum update
sudo yum install python3
```

then run

```
python3 -V
```

to verify that Python is installed.

Comment: still receiving same error

Comment: python found but not fixed totally, screenshout attached. npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /usr/share/nginx/html/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

Comment: Can it find `python3` now?

Comment: yep but ... https://ibb.co/CKNJXpz

Comment: Well that's a different error, not the same error.  It looks like [this is an issue with Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54059433/after-npm-install-an-error-about-a-syntax-error-in-python-appears).   Now you need a newer Node installation.  The one you have is prehistoric in an environment that releases new versions multiple times a month.

Comment: I'm using nodejs v16.14.1 and npm 8.5.0, the latest one.

Comment: Sorry - you said that and I missed it.  I'm out of ideas - something in your environment wants Python 2.  The syntax error you're now getting is because Python changed significantly between 2 and 3 and now your Node build is broken because of it.  You might want to open a new question with your new error.