# Replace Node-Sass with Dart-Sass in Create React App v3.x

Tags: sass, create-react-app, node-sass

Has anybody done this successfully yet? I currently have `node-sass` installed in my CRA project and I'm trying to replace it with `dart-sass` but am experiencing difficulty because the CRA error output is telling me that I need to have `node-sass` installed. Is there any way to let the underlying CRA config know to use my installed `dart-sass` package instead of `node-sass`?

[image]

Answer (score 67, accepted):

There is this [closed issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5282) on CRA repository, so you probably can easily migrate from `node-sass` to Dart Sass just running a few commands.

First of all check your `yarn.lock` or `package-lock.json` to know if the version of the `sass-loader` that your `react-scripts` depends on is 7.2.0 or later.

If so, all that you need is run the following commands:

```
yarn remove node-sass
yarn add sass
```

In my case after that I had to remove the `node_modules` directory and ran the `yarn install` again due to an issue stating the app.

**Notes:**

- The `react-scripts` version I'm using is 4.0.0
- The [npm lib for Dart Sass](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/blob/master/README.md#from-npm) is `sass`
- The use of [`node-sass` is deprecated](https://sass-lang.com/blog/libsass-is-deprecated) since 26 October 2020

Comment: Works like a charm! In my case, only need to remove `node-sass` and add `sass`. I added it as a `devDependency`, this could negatively affect production behaviour? Thanks!

Comment: @sevenlops, the documentation of the CRA says to install it on `dependencies`: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet/

Thera are also a lot of issues questioning the fact of adding dependencies directly on `dependencies`, and it seems adding dependencies to `devDependencies` may lead build to fail in some cases. Check this issue for more info: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2696

Comment: Hi,@MiltonCastro I followed your approach too but ran into an issue after that. `SassError: Expected "n".     ╷ 645 │  .MuiSlider-markLabel.MuiSlider-markLabelActive:nth-last-child(){ ..}` . I tried deleting `node_modules` and `npm install` again after that, but it didn't work for me. Can you help?

Comment: It seems you've successfully migrated to the Dart Sass, but you have a transpilation error on your code. I've already got this kind of issue migrating once, and it was related to a missing semicolon in one of the class attribute. Please try to comment the whole class `.MuiSlider-markLabel.MuiSlider-markLabelActive:nth-last-child` starting on line 645, in order check this error is fix. If so, them you can try to narrowing the commented code until you find the exact point of failure.

Comment: Note that you may need to upgrade your `react-scripts` version first (I was on 3.0.x and had to update to 4.0.3). Older versions may not recognize the `sass` lib. It's pretty easy to upgrade, they have instructions on their releases page. Just install the latest version with `--exact` and probably also reinstall `node_modules`.

Comment: @MiltonCastro What to do if your **sass-loader** is older than **7.2.0**. Actually, mine is **7.1.0**. Should I first update **react-script** and after that follow your steps? Also how to know that version should be exactly above **7.2.0**?

Answer (score 21):

If you are using npm > 6.9 you can create an alias like so

```
npm install node-sass@npm:sass
```

it will install `dart-sass` and you will be able to keep your CRA configuration.

Comment: I'm using npm not yarn, so couldn't follow the first solution.  This one worked great though.

Comment: Darn, guess this broke the `npm outdated` command for some reason!

Comment: @dmikester1: why couldn't you do the above with yarn like so: `yarn add node-sass@yarn:sass`; It seemed to work for me.

Comment: @Jeff I'm not using Yarn though, can I do that even if I'm using NPM?

Comment: yes, I think so. I misread your earlier comment. I thought you needed a solution for yarn. This above answer is already for people using npm. I was just offering a minor variation for people using yarn

Comment: What a neat trick! This saved my bacon.

Answer (score 0):

I had success with:

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm install ci
```