# Cannot Install Node Sass with NPM

Tags: node.js

I am having a hard time installing node-sass on npm, I have attempted to do the following steps:

1. Cleaned the NPM Cache
2. attempted to run "%appdata%\npm-cache" but the folder did not exist.
3. Uninstalling & Re-Installing Node.js & Vue CLI to it's the latest version.

The error code that keeps popping up is:

```js
found 0 vulnerabilities
  Invoking generators...
  Installing additional dependencies...

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Hogar\pvgzcms\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Hogar\pvgzcms\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\Hogar\\pvgzcms\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@15.6.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Hogar\pvgzcms\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\Hogar\pvgzcms\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\Hogar\pvgzcms\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Hogar\pvgzcms\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Hogar\pvgzcms\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Hogar\pvgzcms\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:194:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Hogar\pvgzcms\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\Hogar\pvgzcms\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\Hogar\pvgzcms\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Hogar\pvgzcms\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Hogar\pvgzcms\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Hogar\pvgzcms\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:194:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Users\Hogar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.EXE
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Users\Hogar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                       ^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:333:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:379:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1065:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:296:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19041
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Hogar\\pvgzcms\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Hogar\pvgzcms\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v15.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Hogar\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-17T04_33_14_198Z-debug.log
 ERROR  command failed: npm install --loglevel error --legacy-peer-deps
PS C:\Users\Hogar> found 0 vulnerabilities
found : The term 'found' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ found 0 vulnerabilities
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (found:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\Hogar> ??  Invoking generators...
 : The term '' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+   Invoking generators...
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Users\Hogar> ??  Installing additional dependencies...
 : The term '' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+   Installing additional dependencies...
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Any advice?

Comment: Possible answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53009640/9191712

Comment: That did not work for me, and I have Python 3.9.1 installed on my powershell.

Comment: do you have python 2 install ?

Answer (score 0):

**`node-sass` has been deprecated. You have to use `sass`.**

You can uninstall the old and install the new one

```
npm uninstall node-sass

npm install sass
```

This fixes many issues also during installation