# Node-sass failing when on ruefy:vuetify

Tags: python, vue.js, ubuntu, web

I'm trying to compile a vue.js project from a company I work with and it fails everytime the compiler reaches ruefy:vuetify

[image]

My os is Ubuntu 20.04 and I have both Python 2.7 and 3.9 installed

Both versions of python don't work

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your build is trying to use Python 3.X but your build requires Python 2.X.  It's failing specifically because it's trying to evaluate `print "string"` which is no longer valid in Python 3.X.  It looks to be specifically a problem with node-sass trying to build via an old version of node-gyp.  If you reference [Node.js: Python not found exception due to node-sass and node-gyp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45801457/node-js-python-not-found-exception-due-to-node-sass-and-node-gyp) for what looks like the same problem you should be able to fix this issue by setting the python env explicitly for npm  ex `npm config set python c:\python27\python.exe`.  You also can work around this issue by upgrading your modules. node-gyp has used python 3.X since 5.0.5. See issue https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1977