# Does pyenv-win manage python aliases?

Tags: python, pyenv

I'm running out of ideas.
While building some node project, something explodes on `node-sass` build part and, basically, fails on some Python call:

`` gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2 ``

I said, ok, probably the alias python2 is missing on my PC.
However, throughout various the tutorials/manuals/whatever I haven't found a mention of "pyenv-win not maintaining python2 and python3 aliases".

If it IS the case, please someone confirm this.
If it IS NOT the case... same thing.

Also, maybe I'm looking in the wrong direction.

Comment: Please don't use python 2, it's out of support for a long time.

Comment: Do you have python2 installed? if so I suggest making a shortcut to `python.exe` naming it `python2` and adding it to your PATH, you can make sure it succeeded by running `python2` in cmd

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that was a step in the wrong direction.
This fixed it:

```
nvm use 11.15.0
```

I had a newer version version of node (16.2) and it didn't support... something. And the error was... intelligible in the way it pointer to python2.
You have to love that open source.

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65994982/1632534