# Vue project cannot install dependencies

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

We have a Vue project, when i run the `npm i` code to install all the node packages, show me this error, and i can understanding whats mean or how to solve.

[image]

Comment: which node version are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js: Python not found exception due to node-sass and node-gyp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45801457/node-js-python-not-found-exception-due-to-node-sass-and-node-gyp)

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue changing the **node** version.

At the moment of the problem, the **node** version installed are the **16.3.0**, but change for the **14.17.0 LTS** solve this.