# Python is installed even then I am getting the following error

Tags: python, node.js, npm

while tring to execute `npm install`

The following error occurred, so installed latest version of python, even then i am getting the same issue,

Should i downgrade the python

or

Should i change and path in my system in path

Have any one delat with the same issue

```
npm ERR! path D:\ABC\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe D:\mendix-widget-data-grid\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=

npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@14.17.5 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\mendix-widget-data-grid\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\mendix-widget-data-grid\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\mendix-widget-data-grid\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\mendix-widget-data-grid\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\mendix-widget-data-grid\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\mendix-widget-data-grid\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:192:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\mendix-widget-data-grid\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\mendix-widget-data-grid\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\mendix-widget-data-grid\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\mendix-widget-data-grid\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\mendix-widget-data-grid\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\mendix-widget-data-grid\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:192:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\mendix-widget-data-grid\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\mendix-widget-data-grid\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\mendix-widget-data-grid\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\mendix-widget-data-grid\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\mendix-widget-data-grid\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\mendix-widget-data-grid\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:192:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\mendix-widget-data-grid\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\mendix-widget-data-grid\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\mendix-widget-data-grid\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\mendix-widget-data-grid\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\mendix-widget-data-grid\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\mendix-widget-data-grid\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:192:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location
npm ERR! gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (D:\mendix-widget-data-grid\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (D:\mendix-widget-data-grid\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at callback (D:\mendix-widget-data-grid\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:295:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:192:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\mendix-widget-data-grid\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd D:\mendix-widget-data-grid\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v14.17.5
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
```

Comment: path set for python in environment variables??

Comment: Yes it is configured,In the path added 2 path C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\ and C:\Users\ABCAppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\
Will I be anot able to see the AppData folder? Beacasue I am not able to see it will trying to navigate manually

Comment: Go to cmd type python --version and press enter. You will know if this problem is due to path. If it says something like "didn't find anything named python" then setting up path is causing the problem.

Comment: Your error says it didn't find python.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but it is showing the python version when i give python --version. I AM STILL FACING THE ISSUE, trying it for few days, still no use NEED SOME MORE SUGGESTION

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/q/45801457/15387341