# Getting error while installing node modules

Tags: python, angular, npm

Here is the error log..

```
5919 error gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
5919 error gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
5919 error gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\ADMIN\Downloads\DPM\dpm-repository\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
5919 error gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\ADMIN\Downloads\DPM\dpm-repository\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
5919 error gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\ADMIN\Downloads\DPM\dpm-repository\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
5919 error gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ADMIN\Downloads\DPM\dpm-repository\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
5919 error gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ADMIN\Downloads\DPM\dpm-repository\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
5919 error gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ADMIN\Downloads\DPM\dpm-repository\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
5919 error gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
5919 error gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
5919 error gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\ADMIN\Downloads\DPM\dpm-repository\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
5919 error gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\ADMIN\Downloads\DPM\dpm-repository\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
5919 error gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\ADMIN\Downloads\DPM\dpm-repository\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
5919 error gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ADMIN\Downloads\DPM\dpm-repository\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
5919 error gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ADMIN\Downloads\DPM\dpm-repository\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
5919 error gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\ADMIN\Downloads\DPM\dpm-repository\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
5919 error gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
5919 error gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
5919 error gyp verb `which` failed }
5919 error gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
5919 error gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.EXE
5919 error gyp ERR! configure error
5919 error gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
5919 error gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
5919 error gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
5919 error gyp ERR! stack                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
5919 error gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
5919 error gyp ERR! stack
5919 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:397:12)
5919 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
5919 error gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
5919 error gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
5919 error gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
5919 error gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Downloads\\DPM\\dpm-repository\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
5919 error gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\ADMIN\Downloads\DPM\dpm-repository\node_modules\node-sass
5919 error gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.0
5919 error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
5919 error gyp ERR! not ok
5919 error Build failed with error code: 1
5920 verbose exit 1
```

Comment: maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45801457/node-js-python-not-found-exception-due-to-node-sass-and-node-gyp

Comment: delete the ~/.node-gyp folder and then the ~/.npmrc file. Restart your computer. Then try again. Moreover, more details could be helpful.
The print statement `import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3]` doesn't have parenthesis. Also try again after installing Python2.x

Comment: @h3xh4wk It does not have a parenthesis because node-gyp 3.8 requires python 2.x. `print` became a function from statement in python 3.x :-)

Comment: There is also an option of upgrading the `nodejs` version. Higher versions of `node-gyp` support Python3.x. https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp/v/8.4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

node-gyp is looking for a python installation for working and its not found on the [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) variable of your OS.

`node-gyp` requires python to be installed and available for usage.
From the version documentation of `node-gyp-3.8.0`

- You have to install Python 2.7
- You need to install Windows Build tools

as additional dependencies. If you have already installed `python-2.7`, you can configure gyp with either of the commands below

```
node-gyp --python /path/to/python2.7
```

Or

```
npm config set python /path/to/executable/python2.7
```

For more details, checkout the [documentation here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp/v/3.8.0#on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

Download and install [python2](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2718/). Python310 won’t work because they have slightly different requirements (like parenthesis with print: print() )

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is it! Python 3 was no good in my scenario.