# gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: /Users/sam/.pyenv/versions/3.12.0/bin

Tags: python, macos, path, npm-install, ionic5

`While i was cloning an ionic project in mac, ran npm -i but found. What solution i can do for it ?

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/sam/Projects/IonicProject/{{name}}/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /usr/local/bin/node           /Users/sam/Projects/IonicProject/{{name}}/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/node',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/Users/sam/Projects/IonicProject/{{name}}/node_modules/node-    gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@20.11.0 | darwin | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "/Users/sam/.pyenv/versions/3.12.0/bin" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: /Users/sam/.pyenv/versions/3.12.0/bin
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/Users/sam/Projects/IonicProject/{{nameOfProject}}/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/Users/sam/Projects/IonicProject/{{nameOfProject}}/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/Users/sam/Projects/IonicProject/{{nameOfProject}}/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/sam/Projects/IonicProject/{{nameOfProject}}/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/sam/Projects/IonicProject/{{nameOfProject}}/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/sam/Projects/IonicProject/{{nameOfProject}}/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:202:5)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  /Users/sam/.pyenv/versions/3.12.0/bin Error: not found: /Users/sam/.pyenv/versions/3.12.0/bin
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/Users/sam/Projects/IonicProject/{{nameOfProject}}/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/Users/sam/Projects/IonicProject/{{nameOfProject}}/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/Users/sam/Projects/IonicProject/{{nameOfProject}}/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/sam/Projects/IonicProject/{{nameOfProject}}/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/sam/Projects/IonicProject/{{nameOfProject}}/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/sam/Projects/IonicProject/{{nameOfProject}}/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:202:5) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "/Users/sam/.pyenv/versions/3.12.0/bin", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (/Users/sam/Projects/IonicProject/{{nameOfProject}}/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:484:19)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/Users/sam/Projects/IonicProject/{{nameOfProject}}/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:406:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at F (/Users/sam/Projects/IonicProject/{{nameOfProject}}/node_modules/which/which.js:68:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at E (/Users/sam/Projects/IonicProject/{{nameOfProject}}/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /Users/sam/Projects/IonicProject/{{nameOfProject}}/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /Users/sam/Projects/IonicProject/{{nameOfProject}}/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /Users/sam/Projects/IonicProject/{{nameOfProject}}/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:202:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 23.3.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/sam/Projects/IonicProject/{{nameOfProject}}/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/sam/Projects/IonicProject/{{nameOfProject}}/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v20.11.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/sam/.npm/_logs/2024-03-11T08_02_49_537Z-debug-0.log
```

SOLUTIONS I HAVE TRIED:
1> I have initialised the path declaration in ~./Bash_profile (but still not able to do)

```
export PYTHON=/Users/sam/.pyenv/versions/3.12.0/bin
alias python=/usr/bin/python3
```

2> I have tried installing it through brew also

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting error while installing node modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70519607/getting-error-while-installing-node-modules)

Comment: That is really *old* node-gyp and it requires python 2.7

Comment: @rasjani do i need to downgrade it and use python version 2.7 for it ?

Comment: if you dont want to update your nodejs version or node-gyp itself, you need to have python 2.7.X installed for it to work.

Comment: I strongly advise against using Python 2.7 in 2024. It's deprecated, it's dead, there won't even be security patches for it.