# When I run npm install, a huge error log appears

Tags: node.js, npm, vuejs3, node-modules, npm-install

I've downloaded this github repo (https://github.com/creativetimofficial/vue-black-dashboard), and when I run `npm install` it just throws a huge error log. I have no idea what any of this means.

Im using Arch-based linux distro.

I read that I need to install node-sass or something but I still get the error, so I cant really install anything

npm version: 8.19.1

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/pavel/Documents/vue-black-dashboard/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c -- node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /usr/bin/node /home/pavel/Documents/vue-black-dashboard/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/usr/bin/node',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '/home/pavel/Documents/vue-black-dashboard/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.8.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/home/pavel/Documents/vue-black-dashboard/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/home/pavel/Documents/vue-black-dashboard/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/home/pavel/Documents/vue-black-dashboard/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/pavel/Documents/vue-black-dashboard/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/pavel/Documents/vue-black-dashboard/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/pavel/Documents/vue-black-dashboard/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:211:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/home/pavel/Documents/vue-black-dashboard/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/home/pavel/Documents/vue-black-dashboard/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/home/pavel/Documents/vue-black-dashboard/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/pavel/Documents/vue-black-dashboard/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/pavel/Documents/vue-black-dashboard/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/pavel/Documents/vue-black-dashboard/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:211:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python /usr/bin/python
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /usr/bin/python -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:412:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.19.6-arch1-1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/pavel/Documents/vue-black-dashboard/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /home/pavel/Documents/vue-black-dashboard/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the logs, you can find the following rows:

```
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/home/pavel/Documents/vue-black-dashboard/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/home/pavel/Documents/vue-black-dashboard/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/home/pavel/Documents/vue-black-dashboard/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/pavel/Documents/vue-black-dashboard/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/pavel/Documents/vue-black-dashboard/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/pavel/Documents/vue-black-dashboard/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:211:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/home/pavel/Documents/vue-black-dashboard/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/home/pavel/Documents/vue-black-dashboard/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/home/pavel/Documents/vue-black-dashboard/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/pavel/Documents/vue-black-dashboard/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/pavel/Documents/vue-black-dashboard/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at /home/pavel/Documents/vue-black-dashboard/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:211:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
```

NPM trying to use `pyhton2` to build `node-sass`. Since you probably do not have a `python2`, it trying to use `python` instead, but it (`python3`) throws syntax error.

Looking into very similar SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45801457/node-js-python-not-found-exception-due-to-node-sass-and-node-gyp), I guess you should try installing Python 2.7 in order to build `node-sass`.

Answer (score 0):

You should update Node.js to latest version.
https://nodejs.org/en/