# Node SASS issue | npm install node-sass

Tags: reactjs, npm, sass

I faced a problem while I was trying to install SASS. When I enter this line to the terminal:

```
npm install node-sass
```

VSCode shows me this error. I researched some topics here but not any answers did solve my problem. Can you help me with this? btw I use a MacBook.

[image]

Actually it should install SASS but as you see I am just facing with this error message.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45801457/node-js-python-not-found-exception-due-to-node-sass-and-node-gyp

Comment: Yes. I found the solution. Thanks for your support Sachila. In macOS, we need just download the Python addon (actually VSCode offers it automatically), or ``npm install --global windows-build-tools`` can be the solution.