# React js installing dependencies

Tags: reactjs, npm, dependencies, npm-install

I'm cloning this project:

```
git clone git@github.com:davidzas/react-chat.git
```

Then I just want install dependencies, but I got several errors:

```
$ npm install
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm,
npm WARN old lockfile so supplemental metadata must be fetched from the registry.
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN old lockfile This is a one-time fix-up, please be patient...
npm WARN old lockfile
npm WARN deprecated ini@1.3.5: Please update to ini >=1.3.6 to avoid a prototype pollution issue
npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm WARN deprecated flatten@1.0.3: flatten is deprecated in favor of utility frameworks such as lodash.
npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.0: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated debug@3.2.6: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated debug@3.2.6: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated sane@4.1.0: some dependency vulnerabilities fixed, support for node < 10 dropped, and newer ECMAScript syntax/features added
npm WARN deprecated eslint-loader@3.0.3: This loader has been deprecated. Please use eslint-webpack-plugin
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated html-webpack-plugin@4.0.0-beta.11: please switch to a stable version
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated babel-eslint@10.1.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm WARN deprecated core-js-pure@3.6.5: core-js-pure@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js-pure.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@3.6.5: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documentos\React test\chat\react-chat\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documentos\React test\chat\react-chat\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\user\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\React test\\chat\\react-chat\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.12.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documentos\React test\chat\react-chat\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documentos\React test\chat\react-chat\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documentos\React test\chat\react-chat\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documentos\React test\chat\react-chat\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documentos\React test\chat\react-chat\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documentos\React test\chat\react-chat\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:207:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documentos\React test\chat\react-chat\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documentos\React test\chat\react-chat\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documentos\React test\chat\react-chat\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documentos\React test\chat\react-chat\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documentos\React test\chat\react-chat\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documentos\React test\chat\react-chat\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:207:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Program Files\Python311\python.EXE
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Program Files\Python311\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:412:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:449:11)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:313:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22621
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\user\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\React test\\chat\\react-chat\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documentos\React test\chat\react-chat\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.12.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-05-03T16_37_43_631Z-debug-0.log
```

I was checking the code and I see the file `package.json` and `package-lock.json`, these files are ok, so maybe issue is about another one, what's wrong?

I'm learning about simple chat, so I'm studying this post
[Simple Chat](https://www.fullstacklabs.co/blog/chat-application-react-express-socket-io)

This is about simple chat using react js and node js, with socket

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install node-sass which requires node-gyp to be installed. Node-gyp requires Python to be installed in order for it to work.

you can see in https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass

> Compiling on Windows machines requires the node-gyp prerequisites.

and in https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp

> On Windows
> Install the current version of Python from the Microsoft Store package.

Install Python and then it should work.

Comment: I installed it, and check on cmd and ```Python 3.11.3``` version installed, but tried again ```npm install``` and got the same issues

Comment: Try to do what is written there https://stackoverflow.com/a/53009640/8353201